# Hudson projects RSS feed, build parameters

Tags: parameters, rss, hudson

Is there any way to have Hudson include, in the RSS feed for a project set up in Hudson, the name and value of any build parameters used in a build?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Sure but they would need to setup their own namespace.  a number of rss feeds have extended past generic RSS by including namespaces.  Take a look at Techcrunch's feedburner feed <rss> node.

<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">

Here's an element that isn't part of the RSS spec but linked to the feedburner namespace.  <feedburner:browserFriendly>

So hudson could create a :hudeson namespace and use a node <hudson:buildparams>.

The problem is that no RSS reader that I know of will parse and display the elements in the hudson namespace.  So you would have to pretty much build your own.

Comment: erm.. so you're basically saying that without coding the functionality myself it's not possible..

Comment: depends on your level of need which isn't clearly defined.  Do you need it to show in something like Google Reader? or Do you need it to work with an automated build tool?

Comment: I'm just using Outlook 2010 to consume the RSS feed.  The subject of the "message" says build success/fail.  I'd like the build parameters to appear in the body of the message..

Comment: In that case they would have to put the build params in the body of the message.  Nothing you could do to make it work in outlook.